# NSDictionary won't hold data properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

Basically, I am making an application that saves data into a custom file type. I have it setup to archive a dictionary and save that into a file. It then loads the file, unarchives the dictionary, and puts things where they should be.

Unfortunately, I cannot get my dictionary to actually save the data properly. I have two examples below.

Working

```
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test", @"test2", nil];
```

This will save "test" in the way I want it to, and I can load it perfectly.

Not working

```
NSString *aString = @"test";
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:aString, @"test2", nil];
```

This just gives me a completely empty string when I load the file.

Here is my exact code.

```
- (NSData*)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    [fileContents release];

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

    NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[lifeText stringValue], @"life", [moveText stringValue], @"move", nil];
    [archiver encodeObject:theDictionary forKey:@"SomeKeyValue"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    fileContents = [NSData dataWithData:data];
    [archiver release];

    return fileContents;
}

- (BOOL) readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    fileContents = [data retain];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    loadedFileDictionary = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"SomeKeyValue"] retain];

    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    [unarchiver release];

    NSLog(@"%@", [loadedFileDictionary valueForKey:@"life"]);

    [Card_Building loadLife:[loadedFileDictionary valueForKey:@"life"] move:[loadedFileDictionary valueForKey:@"move"]];

    return YES;
}
```

The other string are set elsewhere for now, but I will need to put them here as well. Then, I use the following code in "Card Builder.m" to put the strings where I want them:

```
+ (void) loadLife:(NSString*)life move:(NSString*)move; {
    lifeString = life;
    moveString = move;
    importData = TRUE;
}
```

I don't see why this will not work. Every time I do test this, I get an empty string and the following error messages:

`2011-06-09 13:33:56.082 HS-Cards[6479:a0f] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.35/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1531`

`2011-06-09 13:33:56.082 HS-Cards[6479:a0f] Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil`

Would somebody please tell me why this won't work?

EDIT: with this updated code, it loads once and gives me the same error messages, but then it refused to load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If that's your exact code, then it looks like the problem is that you're trying to unarchive values for keys (`move`, `range`, `attack`, etc.) that you didn't archive to begin with. You're also putting `lifeValue` into the archived dictionary twice, which is unnecessary, because you're using the same key both times, and it has no real effect:

```
NSString *lifeValue = [lifeText stringValue];
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                                  initWithObjectsAndKeys:lifeValue, @"life", nil];
                                                       // ^^ Once
[theDictionary setObject:[lifeText stringValue] forKey:@"life"];
                         // ^^ Again; doesn't really do anything
```

Comment: I fixed those issues, but it still will not work at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It has been a few days, and I have not heard a response. Am I to assume that you cannot find other problems that may cause this? By the way, I have updated the code.

Comment: What are `lifeString` and `moveString` in `loadLife:move:`? You can't access instance variables in a class method. The connection between the error message involving the `NSTextFieldCell` and this class `CardBuilder` is completely unclear. Where's the text field cell? What is the result of the `NSLog` in `readFromData:...`?

Comment: The result is what it should be. Everything works fine when I load a file, but then I get the error message, and I cannot load again. As for the `lifeString` and `moveString`, those are above the `@interface` in my .h file.

Comment: Justin, you simply haven't provided enough information to allow anyone to help with this. The error message refers to a text field, and I asked you where that text field was, but you have made no mention of it. You say the result of the `NSLog` is "what it should be", but that when you "test" it, you get an error. Post the declaration of `lifeString` and `moveString` -- "above the `@interface`" doesn't mean a whole lot. If you want help, you need to respond meaningfully to requests for clarification, not simply say "It works except when it doesn't". SO is not a debugging service.